# MySQL Net Connector Issue

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I am using the MySQL Net Connector  (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and I have imported the MySQL database into Visual Studio (ADO.NET Entity Data Model) and created the relations.

I now want to Collect some data from the database into my custom Business Entity and have coded the routing as follows:

```
public List<Property> GetProperties()
{
    using (ncsEntities dataContext = this.ncsDataContext)
    {

        // Begin Test #1
        var q1 = from p in dataContext.ra_properties.Top("3")
                 where p.street_id > 0
                 select p;

        List<ra_properties> list1 = q1.ToList();
        // End Test #1   list2 is populated as expected
        // The property ra_streets is populated and is not null


        // Begin Test #2
        var q2 = from p in dataContext.ra_properties.Top("3")
                 where p.street_id > 0
                 select new Property
                 {
                     Key2 = p.valuation_id,
                     Address = "Some Dummy Value"
                 };

        List<Property> list2 = q2.ToList();
        // End Test #2
        // list2 is populated as expected.


        // Begin Test #3
        var q3 = from p in dataContext.ra_properties.Top("3")
                 where p.street_id > 0
                 select new Property
                 {
                     Key2 = p.valuation_id,
                     Address = (p.ra_streets == null || p.ra_streets.address_1 == null) ? string.Empty : p.ra_streets.address_1
                 };

        List<Property> list3 = q3.ToList();
        // End Test #3
        // This Test Fails.  The exception message is
        // Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

        return list3;

    }
}
```

I can not figure out why the last Test does not work.  It fails with the exception message Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Test it one by one..make sure your connections string is also correct...if you are really connected.

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Stack Trace System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<MVVM.Property>.GetResults(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption? forMergeOption) + 0x96 bytes
  System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<MVVM.Property>.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() + 0x2d bytes
  mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.List<MVVM.Property>.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MVVM.Property> collection) + 0x13c bytes

Comment: I am using Fluent nHibernate with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add explicit reference to **ra_streets** in your query.
I cannot test it at the moment but it seems like it is the case.

Try to change it to

```
// Begin Test #3
var q3 = from p in dataContext.ra_properties.Include("ra_streets").Top("3")
         where p.street_id > 0
         select new Property
         {
             Key2 = p.valuation_id,
             Address = (p.ra_streets == null || p.ra_streets.address_1 == null) ? string.Empty : p.ra_streets.address_1
         };
```

and see if it works?

Comment: I tested the above with the Include clause, but it did not change the result.  The error message is still the same.